# How can I add bias using pytorch to a neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

If I have this neural network (NN):

```
 class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes, p=dropout):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=p)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        out = F.relu(  self.dropout(self.fc2(out)))
        out = self.fc3(out)
        return out
```

How do you add bias to it? For instance, on the hidden layer. I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the layer you are using. Some do not have that option. In linear, for example, you can use:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size, bias =False) # Either true or false, the default is true.
```

In [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) you can see for other types of layers if they have a bias option or not.

Comment: you write bias = true and then what ? how do you optimise the bias ? or is it done automatically with the other weights?

Comment: What do you mean by optimizing? If you mean doing the backpropagation in order to update the values it is done automatically yes as the weights are.

Comment: @Marine Galantin `nn.Linear` layers default to `bias=True` so in your original example all your layers already have a bias parameter. And yes, both `bias` and `weight` are automatically registered as parameters for the layer so assuming you use optimizers in the standard way then the bias term will be updated on each `optimizer.step()`.